# ¿Por qué no funciona el parámetro al crear una lista dinámica?

Tags: java

Estoy creando listas dinámicas que se puedan reutilizar. Al meter datos de tipo String, Integer almacena y muestra perfectamente, pero al intentar meter un objeto de una clase que he hecho yo no funciona y enseña lo que creo que es hexadecimal.

El código es el siguiente:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    Coche mercedes = new Coche("Mercedes",2000);
    ListaDinamica<Coche> listaCoches = new ListaDinamica<Coche>();
    listaCoches.insertar(mercedes);
    listaCoches.obtenerTodo();
    
    ListaDinamica<String> lista = new ListaDinamica<String>();
    
    lista.insertar("A");
    lista.insertar("B");
    lista.insertar("C");
    
    lista.obtenerTodo();
    
}
```

La clase Coche solo tiene getters setters y constructor que recibe los parámetros y se los cambia.

La clase de la lista dinámica es la siguiente:

```
public class ListaDinamica<T> {
Nodo cabeza;
int tamano;

private class Nodo {
    private T info;
    private Nodo siguiente;
    
    public Nodo(T info) {
        this.info = info;
        siguiente = null;
    }
    
    public T getInfo() {
        return info;
    }

    public Nodo getSiguiente() {
        return siguiente;
    }

    public void setSiguiente(Nodo siguiente) {
        this.siguiente = siguiente;
    }
}

public ListaDinamica() {
    tamano = 0;
    cabeza = null;
}

public void insertar(T info) {
    if (cabeza == null) 
    {
        cabeza = new Nodo(info);
    }
    else
    {
        Nodo nuevo = new Nodo(info);
        nuevo.setSiguiente(cabeza);
        cabeza = nuevo;
    }
    tamano++;
}
```

La funcion de obtenerTodo recorre la lista e imprime cada cosa. Este es el output que hace:

source.Coche@4c203ea1
source.Coche@7c30a502

C
B
A

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No es problema de la Lista. Toda clase debe sobreescribir el método `toString()` para que devuelva una cadena personalizada para esa clase, si no se hace se usará el método `toString()` que se hereda de la clase Object y ese método es el que imprime cosas como `source.Coche@7c30a502`.

```
class Coche{

    private String  nombre;
    private int precio;

    public Coche(String nombre, int precio){
      this.nombre = nombre;
      this.precio = precio;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString(){
      return "nombre: " + nombre + " precio: " +precio;
    }
  
  }
}
```

Comment: Efectivamente eso era. Muchas gracias por la explicación!